# Connect iOS Swift app to a symfony app

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, symfony

I want to connect a swift application to a symfony web application and I don't know which/best way I can do that. I thought I could make a http request to the symfony web and post a form or I could connect directly to the mysql database and save/read directly and manage the entity relationships by my own logic. Are those options possible? Is there another? Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Do you control the Symfony app? In that case it would be easiest to implement an API for the action(s) you want to be able to perform from the Swift app.

Comment: Yes, I control the symfony app. Thanks for the reply, I will look into this option